# How to correctly set a cookieless subdomain using Joomla?

Tags: joomla-2.5

I have a website: mydomain.com and a cdn subdomain cdn.mydomain.com .

I am using it as a Content Delivery Network but I am also using Cloudflare.

What I did is:

1. Created the subdomain in my cPanel with the following record: cdn.mydomain.com CNAME mydomain.com (TTL 14400)
2. Went to Cloudflare DNS, deleted the A record for cdn.mydomain.com and replaced with a CNAME record (the same of cPanel) 3) I setted a Plugin for Joomla so the content is now served by cdn.mydomain.com and this works.

Now, I would like to know how to do two things:

1. Set cdn.mydomain.com as a Cookieless Domain. I tried setting the cookie domain as mydomain.com in the Joomla Backend but this causes login problems (Invalid Token and similiar ones)
2. Ensure cdn.mydomain.com is not vieweable by users and, mostly important, Google Bot. Is there a way to do this in my robots.txt file, maybe..

Comment: I don't believe this is an actual Joomla related issue, but something you may want to ask on ServerFault or Stackoverflow

Comment: On Stackoverflow they said to ask it here. Also, a cookieless Joomla domain and the robots.txt file of Joomla should be a Joomla related issue.

Comment: Maybe you should just describe what you want to achieve. Basic wording without technical or non-technical terms like "cookieless domain".